# How to know my Android application has been upgraded in order to reset an alarm?

Tags: android

I noticed that an alarm is disabled when the application which sets this alarm has been upgraded. **Is that true ?**

Until now, I used the `SharedPreferences` with a `FIRST_RUN` key in order to know if it's the first run of my application. If I don't find this key, I enable the alarm and set `FIRST_RUN` to false, else I do nothing.

But I noticed also that these preferences remain intact between app upgrade !

So after an upgrade, the `FIRST_RUN` key is already false, so I do nothing while my alarm need to be enabled.

How to handle such case ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've never tried this myself, but what about creating a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to the [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) Intent?

I've thought about trying this before, but I'm not sure if there's a chicken-and-egg problem with it or not (e.g., does the Intent get sent before the new upgraded application can receive it?).  Worth a try, though.

Comment: Yes it works ! Thanks Daniel, actually the intent is sent just after the upgrade so my receiver is able to catch it. I'm just wondering now if my receiver will be triggered at each upgrade of any application ?

Comment: It will trigger each time you upgrade, however in the docs it says that you can look at the Intent's data and it will tell you the name of the package.  Therefore, you can use intent filters to filter out all package replacements that aren't your own.

Comment: Does the app need special permissions to listen to PACKAGE_REPLACED?

Comment: As of API 12 you can use MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: Please do not use this anymore. It will launch your app process for every upgrade of every app, which is extremely inefficient. The only way to filter an Intent with this action to restrict it to your app is by using the ssp attribute which is only available on API 19+, so I recommend MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED only.

Comment: If your using API level 12 and above you can use the MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED for your own app.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Answer (score 93):

> Solution by Daniel Lew :

Need a receiver with the following lines in manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".OnUpgradeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" android:path="your.app.package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`android:path` is used in order to prevent `OnUpgradeReceiver` to be triggered by any upgrade of any application.

Comment: The path part is only used if the scheme refers to a hierarchical URI. In the case of "package" which does not refer to a hierarchical URI, you cannot pass a path string. However, <data android:scheme="package"/> will attach your application package to the URI ("package:your.app.package") so you don't need to pass a path anyway.

Comment: Does the app need special permissions to listen to PACKAGE_REPLACED?

Comment: No the app doesn't need special permission

Comment: android:path was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: if i want to restart my app in this case, I need a separate app for this receiver, right?

Comment: will it also work for a new install? or I'll have to handle that separately using sharedprefs or something?

Comment: is there a way to debug "onReceive" method with this action?

Comment: After testing under Android 4.2, I confirm none of the above solutions properly filter the Intent to your app only: if you specify the scheme only, you get every Intent. If you specify both scheme and path, you get every Intent too because the URI is not hierarchical. The only thing that works is using ssp instead of path, which requires API 19. So better use MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED (API 12+) or nothing. Recommended read: https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-ssp-data-intent-filter/

Answer (score 23):

Simply, listen to the `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` ... This `INTENT` will notify you if a new version of your application has been installed over an existing one

Note: This intent can is available starting from API 12

Comment: This should be the only recommended solution. There is no way to properly filter android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED for the local app only before API 19, and having this Intent triggering your app launch for every app install is hugely inefficient.

Answer (score 21):

For the Android API level 12 and above, you need to register BroadcastReceiver with action [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you're supporting modern Android OSes. For most apps (Gingerbread is at 1% at this point of market share), using MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED simplifies the broadcast receiver code.