# Is there a way to restart a service after upgrading the application on Android?

Tags: android

After upgrading my application I would like the service to restart if it was running before.  Is there any way to do this?  I didn't see any Broadcast Intents that I could register for in the manifest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are right that you should be using a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Have a look at [this question about restarting Alarms on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133986/how-to-know-my-android-application-has-been-upgraded-in-order-to-reset-an-alarm); it shows how you can use the [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) Intent to see when an application is upgraded.