# Auto-restart app after market update

Tags: android, service, google-play, auto-update

Anytime I publish a new version of my app in the Market, if the user had enabled the "auto update" option,  the app will be updated automatically.

The app contains a service that runs constantly. But when the automatic update happens, the old running app is killed, but the new one is not started.
Since the update happens mostly transparently to the user, it makes sense that the app's service should be started again automatically after the update so that there is almost no interruption of the service.

It's a bit difficult to test this with a real update from the market, so I'm using the following two adb commands to simulate this update process.
Install of the 1st version:

```
adb install oldversion.apk
```

Automatic update:

```
adb install -r newversion.apk
```

After I run the second command, the app gets successfully updated, but it has been stopped and not restarted.

**How can we make the new version's service start automatically?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728016/android-restart-application-after-update-action-package-replaced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's something you'll have to test carefully but you should be able to catch it with a broadcast receiver with the action [Intent.ACTION_PACKAGED_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

Then you start the service from your receiver.

Comment: I am trying But Not Working... I tried http://pastie.org/8223893 Can You Give Suggestion??

Comment: I think using ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED will be better ? As it is just being sent to the package being updated, not all packages.

Comment: As the android document
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

So this  Intent.ACTION_PACKAGED_REPLACED is still working ?

Answer (score 9):

If your app is running on `API 12` or higher, I would recommend registering a `BroadcastReceiver` listening to `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.

This Intent is only triggered if YOUR application got an update.

Answer (score 1):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` to `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

Then, compare `EXTRA_UID` with your own. If it matches, you can start your service again.