# Restart Application after update from playstore

Tags: android, autostart

I have an app that is started on bootup via manifest entries:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.vwp.owmini.BootUpReceiver"
 android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

This app itself starts - dependent on configuration - a foreground service and brings own Activity to background. This works well and without problems.

But: when the app is updated because a new version is available in Playstore, it is stopped but not restarted afterwards.

So: how can I tell Android to restart this app after an (automated) update from Playstore?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [another SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572154/auto-restart-app-after-market-update)

> Register a BroadcastReceiver to Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
>
> Then, compare EXTRA_UID with your own. If it matches, you can start
>   your service again.