# Upgrading ionic Application came from Play Store

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Is there a possible way to upgrade an Ionic app came from the playstore  without exiting the Application

Comment: Can you give some context as to why you want to do this. An better scenario may be to restart the app immediately after update. A similar problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572154/auto-restart-app-after-market-update However with this solution you will have to write some specific android code.

Comment: yeah your right after upgrading the app, it will restart and notify the user that the upgrade is successfully finished, i mean exiting the app is the users of the app dont want to logout , is there a possible way in ionic to do that?

Comment: You can store whether the user is logged in or not. This information can be stored in localstorage, however if you want to be sure the log-in status remains you can look at websql in ionic apps (or SqlStorage if using ionic v2) http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/

Comment: I already store the User in Sqlite the thing that i want to do is , to upgrade the version of the app.
ex.
  App V1 to App V2 , while the user is inside the APp