# Android application uninstall listner

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I WANT to make an application in which i want to receive a signal or anything else if user try to uninstall my application
is there any way to do that ?
Please help

Here is my manifest of my demo application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.uninstalldefence"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.uninstalldefence.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.uninstalldefence.BootReceiver"
            android:label="Bilal" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="Package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />

    <Uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

</manifest>
```

and here is my broadcast receiver. But it didn't work
Can you please provide any help ?
    package com.example.uninstalldefence;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Receive install the radio
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
            String packageName = intent.getDataString();
            System.out.println("installed:" + packageName
                    + "package name of the program");
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Added!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        // Receive uninstall broadcast
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            String packageName = intent.getDataString();
            System.out.println("uninstall:" + packageName
                    + "package name of the program");
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Removed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android:Listen to own application uninstall event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475765/androidlisten-to-own-application-uninstall-event)

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)

Here is an post. I dont know your exact application but you could have the user broadcast a unique id everytime they start the app. This way you could gather how many 'active' users you have rather than how people have your app installed.

---

1) It is not possible to run code before your app is installed as stated in the documents.

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Comment: Hey i have added my code please check if you help me ?

Comment: Your code will can only detect when other apps are being uninstalled.
So the work around I suggested is to keep track of how many 'active' users you have on the server side. _You can define active as: users who have used you app within the last week._