# How can i get (handle) Uninstall event of Application in android?

Tags: android, mobile-application

i want to handle uninstall event of application in android like Google Play shown active user and if i remove app then it also increase in-active user count.

Comment: You can do it by using google analytics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to own application uninstall event on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475765/listen-to-own-application-uninstall-event-on-android)

Comment: But i want to update it on my own server ....like if application is uninstall then give me some alert on my server that your app uninstall

Comment: it's impossible. You can't run code on uninstall. You don't control uninstall process, and the time when app begins uninstalling, it's processes are getting killed instantly, and you can't run any code when process is killed

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the GCM/FCM to figure out the registration status.
If you try to send a message to an uninstalled device, it will fail with the response of "NotRegistered".

Take a look at this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#response

Hope its not too late.