# Email notification after Uninstalling App

Tags: android, operating-system

How to send email notification to developer when a user uninstalls the app ?
The email should be send immediately after uninstalling app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen to own application uninstall event on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475765/listen-to-own-application-uninstall-event-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The design of Android is laid out in a way that this should not be possible without abusing exploits / security issues.