# Auto Restart Service After Auto Update From Google Play

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my Android application has been upgraded in order to reset an alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133986/how-to-know-my-android-application-has-been-upgraded-in-order-to-reset-an-alarm)

I have a app run as service and published in google play.  I face on a problem that when I have a new version release and publish to google play that all device will auto update but the service will not be restart until open app or reboot.

I want to know how to resolve this problem like facebook, whatsapp....

Please Help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133986/how-to-know-my-android-application-has-been-upgraded-in-order-to-reset-an-alarm. You should be able to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` to tell when your app is updated.

Comment: "ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" only for API Level 12 to use.  How about API level 8 to 11?

Comment: You should receive `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` as of API level 3, and the data of this `Intent` should contain the name of the package that was upgraded. You can check this data to see if it was your package that was upgraded.