# Can i force users to uninstall my application within update of google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console

I got a question about the Google play console, I published the new update of my application, but I need specific users (Android 33 latest version) to reinstall my application through the update, is there any option that could help me to make the google play uninstall the application then install the new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible and probably not desirable as users may lose their app data (which may be ok depending on the user case). However, if the device backup is enabled and your app supports it, app data is usually restored when the app is reinstalled - including databases and preferences. So that will very likely not really help.

Instead, you should implement a patching mechanism that is executed for the specific users after the update was installed.

Depending on what you need to change, there are several ways to implement:

- **SQLite** [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) offers [`onUpgrade(..)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) to migrate data from one version to another.
- **For other things**, you can always implement such a simple patch mechanism yourself depending on what you need to change based upon `SharedPreferences` as described here: [How to run code only when my app is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14577189/2310221).

Comment: We don't store user data in the application, 
We run the service, but the service stopped suddenly in previous versions, we pushed a new version, but in order to activate this service, the users (Android 33) must re-install the app.

Thanks for your response.