# Run extended Application.class when app update

Tags: java, android, notifications, push

I have an application on Google Play. And now I want to integrate push-notification library in my application. So I initialize this and register user in my class extended Application.class. Some people update application on Google Play automatically and not open this. And registration on push-services will be only when user launch application. So I want that my class with init library and register user in push-service will be run when application updated from Google Play. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` with this action: `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` ([How to know my Android application has been upgraded in order to reset an alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133986/how-to-know-my-android-application-has-been-upgraded-in-order-to-reset-an-alarm)).

You can register a user once `onReceive` is called. It will be triggered even if the app is closed because the receiver is registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Just make sure it's not triggered while updating other apps.